# pushing in git with multiple developers file conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, branching-and-merging

Scenario:
2 developers work on the same project and each dev builds a new feature. Some files of the project are used by both devs and therefore are changed by them.
when the first dev pushes into the production system everything is fine. but when the second dev pushes, what will happen?

Questions:
Does git change the deltas IN the affected files so that no dev has to look through it to find and fix the changes manually? Or does git only track the versions and overwrites the first push with the second one? Or occurs an even different thing?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting with a misconception:  Git does not keep commits as deltas.<sup>1</sup>  Any given commit stores a complete directory tree with all its files whole.  Given a commit SHA-1 ID, to see the contents of a file whose name is, e.g., `top/mid/bottom.ext`, you:

1. extract the tree for the commit (by extracting the commit, which has this tree's SHA-1 ID) and find its subtree named `top`.  This includes the SHA-1 ID of that subtree.
2. extract that tree and find the subtree named `mid` (which gives yet another SHA-1)
3. extract that tree and find the blob (file) named `bottom.ext`, which gives you one last SHA-1
4. extract the blob using its SHA-1.  This is the full contents of the file.

This is different from many other version control systems, which store changes as deltas and must reconstruct either the "newer" file (first version is stored directly, diffs move forward in time) or any "older" file (last version stored directly, diffs move backwards in time).

Aside from that, each commit has, along with a tree SHA-1 ID, a set of "parent commits".  Doing a transitive closure over every commit's parents produces a directed-acyclic-graph (or possibly multiple DAGs).  The edges in this graph are what people like to think of as "branches" (though git computes them dynamically; a "branch name" simply labels a node in the graph).

All that said, when you do a `git push`, you contact the remote repo and get his idea of which branch names correspond to which commit-IDs, and propose that some particular branch name(s) be moved to different commit-ID(s).  You also send over any "missing" SHA-1 IDs and the data needed to reconstruct the trees, files, tags, and/or commits for those.  The remote repo considers your request ("please change `develop` from commit ID 1234567, to commit ID ba98765") and accepts or rejects it, usually on the basis of whether this adds new commits to the branch, without removing any old ones.

If developer 1 pushes first, and adds some new commit(s) to branch `develop`, all goes well so far.  Then when developer 2 pushes, her commits she's added to `develop` are new, but they instruct the remote repo to delete developer 1's commit(s).  When everyone started out they had something like this (cloned from the central server):

```
...<--B<--C<--D<--E       <-- develop
```

where `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E` represent commit nodes (identified by those SHA-1 IDs, which are too painful for humans to use so we have the name `develop` to keep track of the SHA-1 ID for `E`).

When developer 1 adds a commit, this becomes (on his own repo):

```
...<--B<--C<--D<--E<--F   <-- develop
```

If he pushes this to the central server, then adding `F` is fine, it's a new commit that is "downstream".  So the server adds `F` and changes `develop` to have that ID.

Meanwhile developer 2 adds a commit but she gets this:

```
...<--B<--C<--D<--E<--G   <-- develop
```

Her SHA-1 ID does not match (because SHA-1 IDs are globally unique: they're a cryptographic hash of the commit, including all its trees and files).  When she goes to push this, the central server will see that she's proposing to add `G`, but to do so, remove `F`.  (Remember that the commit ID contains the parent ID(s), so `G` *must* point to `E`.  It cannot be altered: changing even a single bit anywhere in the commit or its contents changes the SHA-1 ID.)

With a normal (not "force") push, the server will reject this.

Developer 2 must then `git fetch` (or equivalent) to pick up commit `F`, giving her this:

```
...<--B<--C<--D<--E<--G   <-- develop
                   \
                    `-F   <-- origin/develop
```

(`origin` being the "remote" that names the central server).

It's now up to her to figure out how to combine `F` and `G`.  The two easy and automated alternatives are:

- rebase `G` onto `F`
- make a "merge commit" combining `G` and `F` into `M`

To rebase `G` onto `F` she needs only to run `git rebase` (assuming the usual tracking branch setup).  This will diff `G` against `E` (to obtain a delta—git is not storing deltas!), then attempt to apply the delta to `F`.  If the automated delta-apply works, she gets a modified copy of `G`—call it `G'`:

```
...<--B<--C<--D<--E<--G
                   \
                    F     <-- origin/develop
                     \
                      G'  <-- develop
```

The old `G` no longer has a label, so it's abandoned and eventually garbage-collected.<sup>2</sup>  The new `G'` is a direct descendent of `F` and can now be pushed.

Her other option, the merge, creates a new commit `M`, by doing a standard three-way merge:

```
...-B--C--D--E--G--M      <-- develop
              \   /
                F         <-- origin/develop
```

The new commit may be pushed back to the server because `M` has `F` as an ancestor, so this retains commit `F` on the server.

The force-push option (instead of rebasing or merging) is still an option, but generally not a good one, because it removes commit `F` from the chain of commits on the branch whose tip is labeled `develop`.

The question of whether to rebase or merge is one of preference.  Merges add extra commit nodes and make it harder to see what happened, but the main reason it's harder is that it depicts what *really* happened.  Rebasing makes it look much simpler—it "looks like" developer 2 waited for developer 1 to finish his work, and then wrote hers based on his.  But that's not really what happened, and often enough, commit time stamps will show that.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git *does* do delta-compression internally, but in a very different way.  In theory, git could compress a file's contents against the message in a commit, for instance (or vice versa).  This delta compression keeps the size of what git calls a "pack file" small.  Trees can be compressed against other trees, so if you add or remote a single file in a large directory, the corresponding sub-tree may have delta-compression applied.  For performance and convenience, git objects are kept "de-deltified" as "loose objects" and "re-packed" into new packs automatically.  Loose objects are [deflate-compressed](http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-2.html), and compression is used in packs as well.

<sup>2</sup>Garbage collection also does the repacking noted above.  Most commits are retained for a while (90 days by default) via git's "reflog" mechanism, which allows you to (1) find branch commit IDs by date and (2) recover commits deleted by accident, until the reflog entry expires

Comment: Oh my god, that is so brilliant and makes totally sense. Thank you for shedding light on that problem.

Comment: Git's internal design is really quite amazing.  Its UI, on the other hand... :-)

Comment: Yes, one has to get used to the UI. But your answer should be protected, it is so well put. Amazing.

Comment: Excellent comment, but one nit:  objects are not bzipped, they are deflated.  http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-2.html

Comment: very enlightening answer!

Answer (score 3):

When the second developer tries to push his file, git will say that his copy of the repository is not up-to-date, so it will force him to pull/fetch the repository. Then, if git is able to fix the shared file automatically (for example, because the first developer has been working on lines 1-10 and the second on lines 50-100), then it will do so. Otherwise, it will notify the second developer that a conflict happened, and he will have to manually fix the file.

(I assume they're working on the same branch. If they aren't, then the merging problem will occur when branches are merged, but what will happen is essentially the same.)

Comment: That sounds really great. Is that automatic delta merging the best practise with git or are there other ways to do it?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't know. I'm a git user, but not an expert :) But what I described is what I've always experienced, and surely the default behaviour; I doubt there are other ways, but some git gurus might come in handy now :)

Answer (score 0):

Git don't overwrite anything, in this case, Git will ask you to merge manually.

If the two developpers have worked on different branches, developer 2 should be able to pull the changes made by developer 1 on is own repo, and merge is changes.